# How to implement long-link or half-long-link by HttpClient?

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x, android-async-http

I have encountered a situation where I need to check the state of an order. But the remote server wouldn't return the response soon because it would cast a relatively long time.

So somebody recommended me to use long-link or half-long-link of HttpClient. but I never run into such a unknown situation for me. So I wanted to know how to implement it. Does somebody have some good ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your so-called "long-link" or "half-long-link" means "keep-alive", then I thought I got a solution. There is a header called "Connection" which has two arguments to be selected: "Keep-Alive" or "close". In http 1.0, it's "close" by default. But in Http 1.1, "Keep-Alive" is the default value. So, if you want to implement a persistent link, you need to call the method of `setRequestHeader("Connection" , "Keep-Alive")` of `HttpGet/HttpPost/HttpPut` before these requests are executed.

Meanwhile, maybe you already know this below, I hope it will help you:

> Http Keep-Alive seems to be massively misunderstood. Here's a short
>   description of how it works, under both 1.0 and 1.1.
>
> ### HTTP/1.0
>
> Under HTTP 1.0, there is no official specification for how keepalive operates. It was, in essence, tacked on to an existing protocol. If the browser supports keep-alive, it adds an additional header to the request: Connection: Keep-Alive Then, when the server receives this request and generates a response, it also adds a header to the response:
>
> Connection: Keep-Alive Following this, the connection is NOT dropped, but is instead kept open. When the client sends another request, it uses the same connection. This will continue until either the client or the server decides that the conversation is over, and one of them drops the connection.
>
> ### HTTP/1.1
>
> Under HTTP 1.1, the official keepalive method is different. All connections are kept alive, unless stated otherwise with the following header: Connection: close The Connection: Keep-Alive header no longer has any meaning because of this. Additionally, an optional Keep-Alive: header is described, but is so underspecified as to be meaningless. Avoid it. Not reliable HTTP is a stateless protocol - this means that every request is independent of every other. Keep alive doesn’t change that.
>
> Additionally, there is no guarantee that the client or the server will keep the connection open. Even in 1.1, all that is promised is that you will probably get a notice that the connection is being closed. So keepalive is something you should not write your application to rely upon. KeepAlive and POST The HTTP 1.1 spec states that following the body of a POST, there are to be no additional characters.
>
> It also states that "certain" browsers may not follow this spec, putting a CRLF after the body of the POST. Mmm-hmm. As near as I can tell, most browsers follow a POSTed body with a CRLF. There are two ways of dealing with this: Disallow keepalive in the context of a POST request, or ignore CRLF on a line by itself. Most servers deal with this in the latter way, but there's no way to know   how a server will handle it without testing.